# How to include submodules and install them in python setup.py

Tags: python, setup.py, package-managers

If I have a package with the structure

```
package
|_package
   |_ blah.py
   |_ utils
      |_dep1
        |_setup2.py
        |_blah.py
|_setup1.py
```

What should be mentioned in the setup1.py so that it runs the setup in setup2.py too?